# How Microsoft graph detect content type for attachments (not inline attachments in .NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to know how Microsoft graph API determine content type for attachments.

Problem is I get the wrong content-type and I would like to know who is to blame:
[image: Screenshot]

My code for get attachments:

```
var client = await GetClientAsync();
var attachments = await client.Users[mail.OwnerEmail].Messages[mail.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync();
```

[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) doesn't say anything about that.

Did someone send email the wrong way, or `pdf` was not created correctly?

I tried with graph version (old version)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.15.0" />
```

and

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.21.0" />
```

Comment: It likely reads it right from the MIME content of the email. It's possible the server misinterpreted something, but the MIME being wrong is more likely. You can check with GET /me/messages/{id}/$value to get the MIME.